# Не понимаю как в регулярном выражении правильно поставить ленивые квантификаторы

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Никак не могу додуматься как правильно расположить ленивые квантификаторы.
У меня есть следующий код **HTML** -

`<TR CLASS=R4> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN STYLE="w;">К</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN STYLE="w;">48</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN STYLE="w;">П</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=2><SPAN STYLE="w;">551</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD></TD> </TR> <TR CLASS=R4> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN STYLE="w;">и</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN>Да</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD></TD> </TR>`

Моя задача: если в тегах **TR** содержится **Да**, находящийся слева от закрывающего **SPAN**, то просто взять весь тег **TR** при условии только первых вхождений этого тега, т.е. от открывающего до закрывающего.

По понятным причинам `<TR CLASS=R4>.*>Да<\/SPAN>.*<\/TR>` забирает от первого до последнего тега.

Прошу помочь сделать корректное регулярное выражение по постановке задачи. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: HTML лучше парсить с помощью специальных библиотек, например HtmlAgilityPack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = `<TR CLASS=R4> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN STYLE="w;">К</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN STYLE="w;">48</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN STYLE="w;">П</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=2><SPAN STYLE="w;">551</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD></TD> </TR> <TR CLASS=R4> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN STYLE="w;">и</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R" COLSPAN=3><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN>Да</SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD CLASS="R"><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD><SPAN></SPAN></TD> <TD></TD> </TR>`

console.log(s.match(/<TR CLASS=R4>((?!<TR\b).)*>Да<\/SPAN>.*?<\/TR>/)?.[0])
```